# pass variable to modal via POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, bootstrap-modal

i'm trying to send a variable to pint on a modal but I'm getting **Notice: Undefined variable: ordID**

I searched on many other requests but none solve my problem.

My code:
Table with a  to present the modal that will have all information of that line.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
           <tr>
           <th>ID Ordem</th>
           <th>Instalação</th>
           <th>Denominação</th>
           <th>Estado</th>
           <th>Tipo de Manut</th>
           <th>Ver</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

     <?php

         require_once 'edp/configdbedp.php';

              $sql="SELECT * FROM ordens";
              //echo $sql;
              $myData=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);

     while($registos=mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){
       $ordem = $registos['ordem'];
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>' . $registos['ordem'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $registos['locinstsap'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $registos['denominacao'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $registos['pk_idestado'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $registos['pk_sigla'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td align="center"><a id="getUser" class="modalLink" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $ordem; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Ver</a></td>';
     echo "</tr>";
     }

     //mysqli_close($GLOBALS['con']);
      ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

My script to send via POST:

```
    <script>
    $('.modalLink').click(function(){
        var ordem=$(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/edp/php/adm/modalordens.php',
                data:'ordID='+ordem,
                success:function(data){
                  $(".modal-content").html(data);
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

my file modalordens.php

```
<? $ordID = $_POST['ordID'];?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="fam_id">Ordem <?php echo $ordID;?></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <b>DetailsOrdem <?php echo $ordID;?></b>
        <hr></hr>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I can't print **$ordID**, I don't know why

Comment: sometimes I had to change .data('id') to .attr('data-id') for getting a data-id ... try it and tell me if works

Comment: I don't think your data attribute is supposed to be passed like that. Instead of `data:'ordID='ordem,` try `data: {ordID : ordem},`

Comment: But the error is here...data-id="<?php echo $ordem; ?>"... change it to data-id="'.$ordem.'"

Comment: Not going to fix anything but in your while loop, you have `<a id="getUser"` which is no good when using javascript. Ids are meant to be unique. If you try and do anything with this element by referencing the id, you will find that it only works with the first link with that id.

Comment: @Roy I did that and I have the same error

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton same error :/

Comment: @Rasclatt How i do to print in the same table one <a> for each line of the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to pass the ajax data param as an object :

```
<script>
    $('.modalLink').click(function(){
        var ordem=$(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/edp/php/adm/modalordens.php',
                data: { ordID : ordem },
                success:function(data){
                  $(".modal-content").html(data);
                }
            });
    });

</script>
```

And edit the **php opening  tag** on this line :

```
<?php $ordID = $_POST['ordID'];?>
```

Comment: I already tried with that and the error continue.
before <? $ordID = $_POST['ordID'];?> I don't have nothing.

Comment: edit the opening php tag on this line : <?php not <? : <?php $ordID = $_POST['ordID'];?>

Comment: @SimãoAbreu Alternatively, you can enable short tags in your server.

Comment: Yep, but  is discouraged. is not a "best practice"

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax post is wrong it should be like

```
  $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/edp/php/adm/modalordens.php',
                data: {ordID : ordem},
                success:function(data){
                  $(".modal-content").html(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: you can try using

<?php $ordID = $_POST['ordID'];?> this will work